# textField in listView

Tags: android, listview, titanium

This is my first question in this community that refers to the API of titanium studio. I explain: I'm trying to put a textField inside a listView an item, but when compiled and when to focus on the text area will not let me write and when it does it does in other type of listView.

I hope you can help with this

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'#FFF'
});

var plainTemplate = {
    childTemplates: [
        {                            
            type: 'Ti.UI.Label', 
            bindId: 'title',           
            properties: {            
                width: '100%',
                height: 30,
                left: 0,
                top:0
            }
        },

        {
            type: 'Ti.UI.TextArea',
            bindId: 'campo',
            properties: {
                top:60,
                width: '70%',
                left:10,
                height:40
            }
        }

    ],

    events: {click: check }
};

var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
    templates: { 'uncheck': plainTemplate},
    defaultItemTemplate: 'uncheck'
});

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    data.push({

        title : { text: 'row' + i },

        properties : {
            itemId: 'row' + i,
            accessoryType: Ti.UI.LIST_ACCESSORY_TYPE_NONE,
        }
    });
}

var section = Ti.UI.createListSection();
section.setItems(data);
listView.sections = [section];

function check() {
    alert('estas aqui!!');
}

win.add(listView);

win.open();
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have used.

Comment: just try to put your code here so that I can help you. what you ask is not enough to answer..

Comment: I'm not too sure on this. But seems you are referring to same variable which is plainTemplate, for all list view items. Try with using a function to create new text fields each time.

Comment: Let's see ... explain better ..... I have a listView and this has 100 item (rows), each item has different types of objects, such as a Label, etc ..... imageView also includes a TextArea ... .... when you start the app on the device and select the first textArea the first item (first row) .... lower the pond in focus ... texArea writing in the rows that are below.

In short selected a textArea ... anyone ..... and when I write text in this empiesa ........ writing in the textArea which are below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out to remove the top-Property in UITextArea of 60px? That could be the reason, why your textarea is at another position as you've expected:

```
   {
        type: 'Ti.UI.TextArea',
        bindId: 'campo',
        properties: {
            // top: 60   <--- remove that line
            width: '70%',
            left:10,
            height:40
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested your whole code, but i added this value for a top property to a ListView in an App where i am working on and it ended in an similar behaviour as you wrote.